# componentListener getting disabled

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jwindow, componentlistener

I have an unusual issue in which a componentListener/Adapter is being disabled whenever the mouseListener/Adapter detects an event.  In the code below, the `componentMoved()` method override works perfectly until the `mouseClicked()` method override is triggered in the `MouseAdapter()`.  Any ideas how to fix this?

```
public AlertScroller(String msg,Color col) {
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            setShape(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), newHeight));
            if(!isVisible())
                setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent click) {
            if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(click)) {
                autoClear = false;
                scrollOff();
            }
        }
    });
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(compound);
        panel.setBackground(col);

    JLabel imgLbl = new JLabel(msg);
        imgLbl.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,30));

    panel.add(imgLbl);
    setContentPane(panel);
    pack();
}
```

The class that this method is in extends `JWindow`.

Edit: Added the `scrollOff()` method's code.

```
public void scrollOff() {
    Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
    int taskBar = scnMax.bottom;
    int x = screenSize.width - getWidth();
    int yEnd = screenSize.height - taskBar;
    int yStart = this.getBounds().y;
    setLocation(x,yStart);
    int current = yStart;
    newHeight = this.getBounds().height;
    while(current < yEnd) {
        current+=2;
        newHeight = yEnd - current;
        setLocation(x,current);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    dispose();
    Main.alertControl.setAlertActive(false);
}
```

This is basically the exact reverse of the scrollOn() method and works perfectly fine as long as it's triggered by any means other than through the `Listener`.

**Edit 2:** Fixed code below thanks to MadProgrammer's advice

```
public void scrollOff() {
    x = screenSize.width - getWidth();
    yEnd = screenSize.height - taskBar;
    yStart = this.getBounds().y;
    setLocation(x,yStart);
    current = yStart;
    newHeight = this.getBounds().height;

    ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if(current < yEnd) {
                current+=2;
                newHeight = yEnd - current;
                setLocation(x,current);
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(30, action);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start();
    Main.alertControl.setAlertActive(false);
}
```

I also updated the `AlertScroller()` constructor method with an `else if` to hide the window properly when I'm done:

```
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            setShape(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), newHeight));
            if(!isVisible())
                setVisible(true);
            else if(getBounds().y == screenSize.height - taskBar)
                setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Placing `setVisible(false)` anywhere else caused the window to become visible again.

Comment: What is the code of a method `scrollOff()` ?

Comment: Added the `scrollOff()` code.  But note; this method works fine when triggered by anything other than another listener

Comment: The `while` loop is dangerous, the `Thread.sleep` is dangerous and `dispose` is just plain scary...You're violating the single thread rules of Swing.  `dispose` may be disposing of the native peer that is associated with the window, causing no end of issues...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Care to explain how I can do it correctly, then?  I'm still learning Java, so I'm not sure the "correct" way to do this.

Comment: Assuming, you're trying to slide the window on/off screen, you should utilise a Swing `Timer`, which when triggered, would update the position of the Window until it reaches it's target point and which time you would simply change the window visibility.  This assumes you want to reuse the instance of the window...

Comment: Ahh, ok! That makes sense.  Thanks for the tip!  That actually explains another issue I noticed (but wasn't overly concerned with due to the way this is used).  And yes, you assumed correctly on what I was doing.  I'll update the OP once I've correctly implemented the timer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: could you make your last response into an answer, that did actually fix my problem, and I would like to mark that as correct.  Also, at the point I call `dispose()`, I'm basically done with the entire class, and if I do re-use it at all, I re-initialize it.  Is it still bad to call `dispose()` in this case?

Comment: Hopefully that summed it all up ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while loop` is dangerous, the `Thread.sleep` is dangerous and dispose is just plain scary...

You're violating the single thread rules of Swing and blocking the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

`dispose` may be disposing of the native peer that is associated with the window, causing no end of issues...

See [`JWindow#dispose`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) for more details.

Assuming, you're trying to slide the window on/off screen, you should utilise a Swing `Timer`, which when triggered, would update the position of the Window until it reaches it's target point and which time you would simply change the window visibility. This assumes you want to reuse the instance of the window..

See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for clearing that up... and helping me become a better programmer! Lol! In truth, I was originally an artist that started programming because there was no-one else to do it... and even if it was wrong, the code did what was asked of it.

Comment: Funny, I did it the other way around for a while ;)

Comment: Posted my updated code under "Edit 2:" in the OP.  Let me know if I made any other mistakes! Note: I changed several variables to fields rather than local variables so I only had to initialize them once and didn't have to set them to `final`.

Comment: Just make sure that once you no longer the timer, you're stopping it ;)

Comment: I would have caught that one eventually (I hope x.x), lol, thanks for pointing that one out!  Fixing it now.